# SDL clears the window screen when clicking on the window of another software in Linux

Tags: c, drawing, sdl-2

My program is about drawing the Mandelbrot set. I discovered that when I click another window in the operating system (eg. Chrome, or text editor ...) my program clears the screen to black but continues drawing where it finished. It is during drawing. If the drawing is finished and I click another window then nothing clearing happens.

Is there a solution to fix this (eg. switching something on or off in SDL) without tracking all the pixels onto the screen and print the entire pixel matrix all the times?

Minimal code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

enum {WIDTH = 1700, HEIGHT = 950};

int main(){
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Minimal", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, WIDTH, HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
        SDL_Event event;
    bool exit_ = false;
    while (! exit_){
        for (int i = 1; i < WIDTH; i++){
            for (int j = 1; j < HEIGHT; j++){
                SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, i, j);
            }
                SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        }

        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) exit_ = true;
        }



    }
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

*(Note: I haven't got any window event handling in the program.)*

Comment: [mcve]? Screenshots? Linux version, SDL version?

Comment: I don't think framebuffer is required to keep your previous data. If it is important to you, render to texture and then display this texture on screen.

Comment: Is it possible to switch off this clearing behaviour of SDL?

Comment: @csekri I don't think it is SDL but rather rendering backend it uses for hardware accelerated rendering (opengl, d3d, ...). And no, I don't think that would be possible, but there are ways to work it around. You also can detect full redraw event and react accordingly (perform full redraw), and do accumulative draw if there is no such event. But there are still problems with double buffering.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put `SDL_RenderClear(Renderer)` at the top of the while loop.
If you do like that, window will be never cleared after rendering.
For example if you don't clear the window, a moving dot will leave his traces..
I work woth SDL too, and i always do this

Comment: If I put `SDL_RenderClear(Renderer)` in the first line of the while loop then it clears the screen to a homogenous colour but I want to store and  `SDL_RenderPresent(Renderer)` the things I draw related to Mandelbrot set. When I click another window during the process (eg. the terminal) then it calls something event to clear the screen to black.